# How do i remove double notifications? Galaxy s 2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, notifications

I have the newest Samsung Galaxy S2 (SkyRocket) and as a user of Handcent I was able to disable the "double text notifications" on my last Galaxy but on this phone when I go to the main messaing app then the menu button I dont have a settings option.

How can I turn off the notifications so I don't recieve every message twice?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into the Stock Messaging app, hit Menu > Settings, un-check 'Notifications' which has the text stating 'Display message notifications in status bar'.